# a simple c++ program crashes?

Tags: c++, pointers

Write a program that asks the user to enter his or her first name and then last
name, and that then constructs, stores, and displays a third string, consisting of the
user’s last name followed by a comma, a space, and first name.Use char arrays and
functions from the cstring header file.A sample run could look like this:
Enter your first name: Flip
Enter your last name: Fleming
Here’s the information in a single string: Fleming, Flip

```
int main()
{

    char * fName,*lName,*fullName;

    fName = new char;
    cin.getline(fName,100);

    lName=new char;
    cin.getline(lName,100);

    fullName=new char[strlen(lName)+strlen(fName)+3];

    strncpy(fullName,lName,strlen(lName));

    fullName[strlen(lName)]=',';
    fullName[strlen(lName)+1]=' ';


    char* dummy=(char*)fullName[strlen(lName)+2];//making a pointer to the char after the ' ' char to start copying the first name

    strncpy(dummy,fName,strlen(fName));

    dummy[strlen(fName)+strlen(lName)+2]='\0';

    cout<<endl<<endl<<dummy<<endl;



    delete fullName;
    delete lName;
    delete fName;
    return 0;
}
```

why it crashes when i point to a char in the middle of the array and start copying ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
fName = new char;
```

allocates a single char.

```
cin.getline(fName,100);
```

goes way beyond that.

Use `std::string` instead. You'll see that writing C++ code in C++ instead of C makes life a lot easier.

Comment: i know,but it gets the whole line and can cout it correctly

the crash comes after getting the 2 inputs,it gets them right and copies the lName then appends ','+' '

but don't copy fName correctly!

Comment: *Use char arrays and functions from the cstring header file.* - As soon as that assignment is done, switch to std::string.

Comment: @user1609974 no it doesn't. The code gives you undefined behavior. It appears to work correctly because you got lucky (or not, depends on how you look at it). But it's not correct and that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1609974 allocate as many chars as you need (I'd go with something over 100). Nobody is going to give you full working code, but hints will get you there. Try to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `fullName[strlen(lName)+2]` is char, to get the pointer do:

```
char* dummy=fullName + strlen(lName)+2;
```

Comment: it's a char but i casted it !

and this don't work too :/

any other solution ? or even if u can solve the whole problem yourself,it's simple :D

Comment: the problem is not casting, to get the desired address you need to do pointer arithmetic instead of accessing the array element.